# Need to track partition size, is it okay to store metadata in a table?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, data-modeling, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to keep track of the current size of a partition. I am trying to not create wide partitions.
It is not necessary for me to have an exact number, but a rough estimate.
As part of my plan, I intend to maintain meta data for the actual partition in a 'meta_table' and actual data in a 'data_table'

```
meta_table = CREATE TABLE meta_table (user TEXT, partition_id BIGINT, size BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY(user, partition_id));

data_table = CREATE TABLE data_table (user TEXT, partition_id BIGINT, key TEXT, value TEXT, PRIMARY KEY((user, partition_id), key));
```

In order to determine whether I have crossed a certain partition size limit (50 Mb) in data_table, I will read meta_table before writing into data_table. In the case that I have crossed size limit, I will create a new partition and maintain it in meta_table while inserting the data into that new partition_id in data_table, else update size of that partition_id in meta_table and insert into same partition_id in data_table.

Read:Write ratio is 1. Is this okay ? Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra itself will store metadata on the partition sizes, which might work well for you depending on your exact needs.
You have the ability to see the compacted min/max/avg partition size of a table by running:

```
nodetool tablestats <keyspace.table>
```

If you need more exact numbers, you also have the ability to download and use DSBulk: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/install/dsbulkInstall.html

Using a count option, you can pull any specified number of partitions, sorted largest to smallest, as well as the partition key, for example, to see the 10 largest you would run:

```
 dsbulk count --stats.modes partitions --stats.numPartitions 10 -k myKeyspace -t myTable
```

If this needs to be done programmatically on an insert, then perhaps checking the system.size_estimates table would work for you as a way of getting the quick avg size:

```
select avg(mean_partition_size) from system.size_estimates where keyspace_name = 'keyspace' and table_name = 'table';
```

Hopefully one of those will help out.

Comment: What exactly is system.size_estimates ? What does `range` in this table denote ?
How can I get the partition key or or token_id of the partition key of that table if I use `max(mean_partition_size)' ?

Comment: The range columns are just token ranges, if you use vnodes, then you'll see a corresponding number of ranges, and the table is just showing the average partition size for the range. If you need the actual partition key, then you'll want to use DSBulk because it will show the keys you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that yes, you can store whatever data you want but the real question is "what problem are you trying to solve?".

What you are proposing is doing a read-before-write which is expensive so it will affect the performance of your application.

The schema you posted shows that your use case is storing key-value pairs in Cassandra. Since each partition contains just a single cell value, how big do you really expect your partitions to grow? And so, what problem are you trying to solve by storing partition metadata?

Based on the limited detail in your question, it doesn't seem to me that your proposal is a good idea. Cheers!

Comment: I have edited the question. Could you have a look now ?